# AngularJS and ui-sortable(branch 1.2): ng-mouseover breaks after sorting

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui, angularjs-bootstrap

I upgraded my App to AngularJS 1.2 and so also switched to ui-sortable v 1.2.

The sorting is implemented for Accordion-Groups (from ui-bootstrap). With the master-tree version of sortable i could listen to ng-mouseover/ng-mouseleave inside the accordion headers but with the 1.2 version, the mouseevents are only listening as long as i haven't done any sorting. After performing any change to the sortorder, the mouseevents become deaf...

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/n8yms9pb7uJp77zZ9LFK?p=preview

Can anybody give me some advice how to fix that?
Thank you

Comment: Probably shouldn't use `raw.github.com` links in your plunk: `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/angular1.2/src/sortable.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. `

Comment: what would be the correct way? Sortable can't be found via "Find external Libraries"..

Comment: got it: updated to rawgithub.com links

Answer (score 1):

#### Identity Problem.

> `elementInsertedByDropping !== elementSelectedAndDragged`

In the console, one can verify the assertion above.    So that narrows down the category of problem to a relatively familiar one.

I'm learning Angular myself, and I'm also having trouble with ui-sortable; please don't regard my opinions as definitive.  However, I believe that the problem is that the $watch listeners need to be re-bound to the new element, as it is being created asynchronously outside of Angular.

The "ng.$rootScope.Scope" documentation describes this situation somewhat clearly in the $apply section. If I am correct, you would need to either `$scope.$apply(...)` code in your controller, or [preferably] write a custom directive that handles the insertion.

Fortunately, it seems that jQuery-ui-sortable's "update" event can be easily used in a custom directive to ensure that the element is bound.  I found that bloggers [respectTheCode](http://respectthecode.tumblr.com/post/17763802367/angularjs-ng-repeate-with-jqueryui-sortable) and [Michal Ostruszka](http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2012/12/03/sortable-in-angularjs/) discuss the problem of writing jQuery-ui-sortable directives in fairly clear terms;  so does a fellow named Greg Gigon and several others, but I'm only allowed to offer you two links at this point.

If I can provide more precise information at a later point, I will revise this answer;  I'm still learning this stuff myself, and I would like to know how to do something quite similar.

---

[***edit***:  *I'm not familiar enough with Angular-UI-Sortable  to know whether this is a bug or simply missing functionality.*]

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I will consider having a closer look at Michal Ostruszkas Directive if i can't fix the issue with the "official" one. But as @blesh mentiones, submitting an issue on github may be the way for now...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in ui-sortable.

My guess: It seems to be losing the bindings from the event directives, probably because it's destroying the old DOM elements and creating a new ones without re-attaching the scope with `$compile`. [I'd save this plunk and submit and issue on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)